# Unlock features for USB device

Tags: usb, camera, cmos

I have an USB camera that has a 5Mp sensor in it. But the device works only as a 1.3Mp sensor (via 2x2 binning or skipping). The 5Mp sensor is most certainly there (when plugging the device to a windows machine before installing the drivers it reports as a CMOS color 5Mp sensor), but I don't know if the limitation is software based (e.g. via firmware) or hardware based (e.g. a different hw interface between the sensor and the computer). If it matters, the sensor is a Micron MT9P031. Anyway, is there any easy way of knowing if the camera can be hacked to use the full potential of the sensor? thanks,

EDIT1: According to http://www.tucsen.com/Public/upload/download/pdf/Software%20and%20Driver%20download%20links_EN_20210922.pdf the models in question hava a vendor ID VID:0547 and product ID PID:A008 and PID:A004 (for the 1.3Mp and 5Mp respectively) I can confirm I have the A008 PID. Furthermore, this information is lso available in the INF file:

%VID_0547&PID_A008.DeviceDesc%=TuUsb3, USB\VID_0547&PID_A008  ; ISH130
%VID_0547&PID_A004.DeviceDesc%=TuUsb3, USB\VID_0547&PID_A004  ; ISH500

Comment: Welcome to superuser.  The information provided is insufficient for us to help you. What is the camera model?

Comment: What is the operating system? Look up new drivers for that OS.

Comment: Hello, the camera is an Orion Starshoot V 1.3Mp, a rebranded version of the Tucsen ISH line of cameras that are used usually for microscopy. The OS is Windows (I haven't been able to get it to function under linux, as I haven't stumbled upon any documentation about it.) I tried forcing installation of the official ISH500 drivers (the 5Mp version) but the capture software still recognizes it as an ISH130 (the 1.3Mp version). Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you might have wrong drivers, if the default Windows driver identifies the device as 5MP. What resolution can be achieved with the standard default Windows camera app? However, if your PID corresponds to 1.3MP, then it IS 1.3 MP variant.

Comment: I cannot select the USB device as a camera under windows. The device manager lists it as an "imaging device" and not under "cameras". Further, I cannot select it as a "default camera" in control panel.

Comment: And yes, the label indicates it is the 1.3Mp variant but I was wondering if its full resolution could be unlocked. Currently, its resolution is 1272x952 which is the result of skipping every other active pixel (or 2x2 binning) in the 5Mp version. Ref: http://www.tucsen.com/Home/Product/parameter/dataid/7/id/7.html